# How can I use backslashes (\) in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, backslash

I tried many ways to get a ***single backslash*** from an **executed** (I don't mean an input from `html`).

I can get *special characters* as tab, new line and many others then escape them to `\\t` or `\\n` or `\\(someother character)` but I cannot get a single backslash when a *non-special character* is next to it.

I don't want something like:

```
str = "\apple";   // I want this, to return:
console.log(str); // \apple
```

and if I try to get character at 0 then I get `a` instead of `\`.

Comment: Is your question about strings, or regular expressions? Or regular expressions you're creating via strings (e.g., using `new RegExp(string)`)?

Comment: I tried every ways, either regular expressions or string methods, but it really seems that there is no way to handle **verbatim** or **raw** strings in javascript code.

Answer (score 91):

**(See ES2015 update at the end of the answer.)**

You've tagged your question both `string` and `regex`.

In JavaScript, the backslash has special meaning both in string literals and in regular expressions. If you want an actual backslash in the string or regex, you have to write two: `\\`.

The following string starts with **one** backslash, the first one you see in the literal is an *escape character* starting an *escape sequence*. The `\\` escape sequence tells the parser to put a single backslash in the string:

```
var str = "\\I have one backslash";
```

The following regular expression will match a **single** backslash (not two); again, the first one you see in the literal is an escape character starting an escape sequence. The `\\` escape sequence tells the parser to put a single backslash character in the regular expression pattern:

```
var rex = /\\/;
```

If you're using a string to create a regular expression (rather than using a regular expression literal as I did above), note that you're dealing with two levels: The string level, and the regular expression level. So to create a regular expression using a string that matches a single backslash, you end up using **four**:

```
// Matches *one* backslash
var rex = new RegExp("\\\\");
```

That's because first, you're writing a string literal, but you want to actually put backslashes in the resulting string, so you do that with `\\` for each one backslash you want. But your regex *also* requires two `\\` for every one real backslash you want, and so it needs to see two backslashes in the string. Hence, a total of four. This is one of the reasons I avoid using `new RegExp(string)` whenver I can; I get confused easily. :-)

#### ES2015 and ES2018 update

Fast-forward to 2015, and [as Dolphin_Wood points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30748739/157247) the new ES2015 standard gives us template literals, tag functions, and the [`String.raw`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.raw) function:

```
// Yes, this unlikely-looking syntax is actually valid ES2015
let str = String.raw`\apple`;
```

`str` ends up having the characters `\`, `a`, `p`, `p`, `l`, and `e` in it. Just be careful there are no `${` in your template literal, since `${` starts a substitution in a template literal. E.g.:

```
let foo = "bar";
let str = String.raw`\apple${foo}`;
```

...ends up being `\applebar`.

Comment: How do you console.log() the variable with backslash if it was assigned already (because it came back like that from the server)?

Comment: @kev: I don't understand the question.

Comment: `$.ajax({}).done(function(data){console.log(data)})` Output: `Object {apple: "apple"}` but server actually sent: `{"apple": "\apple"}`. Does it need to be escaped on the server or is there a pure client side solution?

Comment: @kev: What the server sent is invalid JSON. JSON (unlike JavaScript) doesn't tolerate undefined escape sequences (`\a`). If that's meant to be a backslash, yes, it must be escaped server-side: `{"apple":"\\apple"}`. (You'd want to even if JSON tolerated invalid escapes, because of `{"nectarine":"\nectarine"}`, where that would be `<CR>ectarine` because `\n` is a newline.)

Comment: It looks like the `\12` kind of restrictions (there were also issues with `\u`, `\x` etc.) went away sometime [after late 2016](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-template-literal-revision/), so in modern browsers the only thing to avoid is `${`

Comment: Seems like plugging directly into the debugger should work, but maybe not:  Firefox 82.0.2 (32-bit)
13:54:43.577 str = String.raw`\apple`;
13:54:43.646 "\\apple"

chrome Version 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (64-bit)
str = String.raw`\apple`
"\apple"

Comment: @captainpuget - Not sure what you mean by "plugging directly into the debugger." Template literals and tagged template functions don't relate to the debugger (any more than anything else does).

Comment: that `String.raw` was the only solution for my problem, thanks.

Comment: ```String.raw`\`;``` doesn't work, but you can cheat and do ```String.raw`\apple`.replace('apple', '');```, it seems to work

Comment: @TBG - Yeah, the backslash escapes the backtick. I think I'd probably use something like ```String.raw`\``.slice(0, -1)```. :-)

Answer (score 25):

Try `String.raw` method:

```
str = String.raw`\apple` // "\apple"
```

Reference here: [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw)

Comment: Just be careful you don't have `${` anywhere in the template literal. :-)

Comment: And you can't have octal literals in template strings either such as `1\2` so this isn't really an effective general technique for avoiding backslash escaping.

Comment: ```String.raw`\`;``` doesn't work, but you can cheat and do ```String.raw`\apple`.replace('apple', '');```, it seems to work

Answer (score 16):

`\` is an escape character, when followed by a non-special character it doesn't become a literal `\`.  Instead, you have to double it `\\`.

```
console.log("\apple");  //-> "apple" 
console.log("\\apple"); //-> "\apple"
```

There is no way to get the original, raw string definition or create a literal string without escape characters.

Comment: raw string becomes possible via es6 [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) method

Answer (score -3):

please try the below one it works for me and I'm getting the output with backslash

```
String sss="dfsdf\\dfds";
System.out.println(sss);
```

Comment: the question is not about Java.