# How to pass a JSON string as an argument?

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have a rather simple method as shown below:

```
var foo = function (str) {
    console.log(str); //{"Field Name": "Value With "Escaped" Content"}
    JSON.parse(str); //fails
} 

foo('{"Field Name": "Value With \"Escaped\" Content"}');
```

The passed argument features intentional backslashes (the string originates from a third party), however, they're absent once the string is passed to the function (see the inline comments).

Can I avoid the issue without manually double-escaping the string? Why doesn't using single slashes around the string itself avoid this issue? Is it possible to retrieve the raw input string?

Comment: you escape `"` because in this context you are declaring a string (btw useless because surrounded by simple quotes), you are not creating escaped double quotes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get backslashes inside a string - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/get-backslashes-inside-a-string-javascript)

Comment: Are you just copy and pasting this JSON into your source code for testing, but in practice the string will come from some API? Then you won't even have this problem in practice! Otherwise, clarify where that string comes from and what you do with it.

Comment: @deceze The function is called with the parameter inlined by a third-party script, I can simply modify the receiving function.

Comment: And this third party script is unable to correctly escape strings to conform to Javascript syntax?

Comment: @deceze I wouldn't be asking this question if that wasn't the case, so yes.

Comment: Then I think you're mostly screwed.

Answer (score 2):

The `\` characters are JSON escape characters but they are also JavaScript escape characters.

You have a JavaScript string literal. When that is parsed by the JavaScript compiler the `\"` will be interpreted as `"`.

The JSON parser therefore gets passed `"` and not `\"`.

> Can I avoid the issue without manually double-escaping the string?

The string needs to be double escaped. You may or may not have to do that manually depending on where the string comes from.

> Why doesn't using single slashes around the string itself avoid this issue?

Because the language design of JavaScript doesn't say that `\` characters are not escape characters in single quoted strings.

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the raw input string without it being parsed?

Comment: @Nit linked post state `String.raw` ES6

Comment: Only by accessing the raw JavaScript and writing a custom parser. (That would be a stupid approach to solving the problem).

Comment: @Nit It is being "parsed" the second you type it into the source code (well, as soon as it is evaluated). The string `"foo\"bar"` in Javascript source code really means `foo"bar`.

Comment: @deceze I understand that, but I was wondering if accessing it is still possible, looks like `String.raw` answers that question, but that's ES6.