# Extracting just the last part of a string

Tags: javascript, escaping

I'm trying to get the username from a JSON property I get returned from Sharepoint's restful API.

The property/string I receive: `"i:0#.w|xyz\tzzjjaa"`

What I want: `"xyz\tzzjjaa"`

I tried: `"i:0#.w|xyz\tzzjjaa".replace("\\","\\\\")`, which returns:
`"i:0#.w|corproot   tzzjjaa"`

Why is this the case? (is the backslash kind of escaping the "t" in the string?)
How can I fix it to just get `"xyz\tzzjjaa"`?

Thanks alot. :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:json] or [tag:sharepoint].

Comment: `"i:0#.w|xyz\tzzjjaa".replace("i:0#.w|", '')` ?

Comment: Split on the pipe?

Comment: `\t` is a tab, so the initial string is not properly escaped.

Comment: ...unless it's meant to have a tab in it, of course.

Comment: So what to do then? This is a username I get from the server... can't change it...

Comment: @epascarello How can I fix this?

Comment: What shilly said...why not just do `string.split("|")[1]` if the format of the string you get is consistent

Comment: Because JS is escaping the part `\t`

Comment: If the \ is supposed to be an \ than you need to double it up when the string is created. My guess sharepoint is not doing that so.... not sure what to do in your case.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = String.raw`i:0#.w|xyz\tzzjjaa`;
console.log(str.split("|")[1]);
```

Assuming you want to keep the backslash see [a really good answer by T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/get-backslashes-inside-a-string-javascript) on using the String.raw function, then split the string on the pipe and take the second part of the resulting array.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/snjfveo6/

If you don't want the backslash you can remove the String.raw part and skip to splitting the string.

Comment: And the support for that is very limited in browsers and looks like you typed it wrong.

Comment: Looks good, tested it in chrome. See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw - it is only support in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Yeah I should note that this is a 2015 standard @epascarello well pointed out!

Comment: It's not working with an `x` instead of `t`: var str = String.raw`i:0#.w|xyz\xzzjjaa`;

Comment: Thanks :) In case there will never be an 'x', your solution is really nice. It's just a real pity we can't even deactivate escaping in a **Raw-String**.

Comment: @SebastianG.Marinescu Yeah it's frustrating [also a known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5016)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "i:0#.w|xyz\tzzjjaa".replace("i:0#.w|", "");
alert(JSON.stringify(str));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sathvikchinnu/wzL0mL44/)

Comment: added demo @Sandrooco

Comment: This works in this case. If however the user-name/-suffix starts with an `x`, it will not work - try:  `str = "i:0#.w|xyz\xzzjjaa".replace("i:0#.w|", "");`

Comment: he haven't mentioned that in the question @SebastianG.Marinescu

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

are you sure it should be `"tzzjjaa"`? `\t` in a quoted string literal (or in the JSON string) is not `\` followed by `t`, it represents a TAB (ASCII Code# 09) character instead!

Comment: @Sandrooco if it is a \ followed by t, then it should be coded as `"i:0#.w|xyz\\tzzjjaa"`, or with the `String.raw` as suggested above. instead of splitting the string, you may still use the replace function in the following manner: `.replace(/^.+\|/,"")`

Answer (score -1):

`\t` in a JS-string is escaped to a Tab-character.

Your best solution as I see it, is to escape it on the server-side.

In your case you will have to write a little server-script, that calls your used API and converts/escapes everything to be ready for your JS. And your JS calls this little server-script.

If your username is **sure to never start with an x after the backslash**, then:

Either go with [JNewtons's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39080557/1166642) and use the `String.raw`-method, or for wider support use the `Stringify`-method by [Sathvik Cheela](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39080658/1166642).

But if there is a **chance that it might start with an x after the backslash**, you have currently no way to solve this in the Frontend in JavaScript – only in *a backend*.

Comment: Why can't people read the question and comments? I told that I can't change the server stuff because it's SP.

Comment: I am not talking about the already existing API – but you could write a little PHP-snippet as broker. Of course I am assuming that you are allowed to work on the server.

Comment: If you are the Admin on the SP-Site, then you have to change it: Escape the response correctly. If not, _they_ have to change it. Your response from the API should be correctly JSON-encoded.

Comment: As said I can't change it. Never mind, found a good solution.

Comment: @Sandrooco: I'm curious, what is your solution?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(result.Author.Name).split("|")[1].slice(0, -1).replace("\\\\", "\\");`- a bit dirty but the safest. Working all the way down to IE8.

Comment: And your Author-Name can never contain a `\x` in it?