# Eloquent Javascript Chapter 3 mountain example

Tags: javascript, function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytzQj.png)

On line 11 why is there a double backward slash "\" When the end production only produces a single slash "\" I am confused as to why mountain doesn't look like this "/''''\"
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get backslashes inside a string - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/get-backslashes-inside-a-string-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

When you put a backward slash '\' in a string it has to be escaped with another backward slash since it is a special character in strings.

The backslash is used to for special constructs like tab: `\t` or newline: `\n`, so to just get a backslash in the string you have to do it twice.

Comment: ok thanks! so essentially i would need to add a second backward slash \ for every one that i wanted in a string