# How to split escape character \ in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

How to split escape character in this string?

[image]

already tried doing this

```
str = str.split('\\');

console.log(str);
```

this is the output

[image]

I want an output something like this

[image]

please help. thank you.

Comment: In `let str = 'cba\common'`, there is no literal ``\``.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I dont understand what do you mean theres no literal \

Comment: When writing a question, you should include code in the form of **text** and  *not* pictures.

Comment: See the ["Get backslashes inside a string - Javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/get-backslashes-inside-a-string-javascript)  question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape character is consumed when the string literal is parsed so there are no `\` characters in the string to replace.

It is too late to fix this programmatically. You need to edit the original source code to represent `\` characters as `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a string like this, you have to use the double backslash.

```
var str = "..\..\common\core\services\shared.service";
console.log(str); // "....commoncoreservicesshared.service"

// Correct way
var str = "..\\..\\common\\core\\services\\shared.service";
console.log(str); // "..\..\common\core\services\shared.service"
// Then use this:
str.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```