# Using the '\' character as text in a string

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use the character '\' inside a string and have it be read as text?

Can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere.

Comment: `'\\'`Google for "escaping".

Comment: Thank you! I did google escaping, but didn't find a clear answer on getting the character to be stored in the string.

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/get-backslashes-inside-a-string-javascript

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/get-backslashes-inside-a-string-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Backslash(`\`) is an escape character, & to use backslash you need to *escape* it using another backslash.`\\` will output only single `\`

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hello\\"
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('\\');
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can use it

```
let str = `\ Hello World \`;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use double backslash(\\) . As single backslash (\)is a reserve word in JavaScript for escape character.