# How do I match a single word in Javascript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I just want to match one word (\w+) after a pattern in javascript.

Here is my simple test code:

```
(new RegExp("apple:\w+")).test("apple:asdf");
```

However, I am being told by javascript that the pattern does not match. This goes against pretty much everything I'm used to about regex matching. Even when I tested it on regex101.com I got a match.

What is the convention used for matching a word?

Comment: don't forget to anchor the regex with `^...$` if you require the entire input to match.   As written it'll match `orangesandapple:adsf!!!!`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/how-can-i-use-backslashes-in-a-string). Where's that non-binding closing vote when I need one? )

Comment: @raina77ow I'd say it's not a duplicate, because the OP here _didn't know he needed to escape them_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to escape that slash inside your string literal, otherwise it'll be just lost:

```
const slashIsLost = "apple:\w+";
console.log(slashIsLost); // apple:w+

const slashIsEscaped = "apple:\\w+";
console.log(slashIsEscaped ); // apple:\w+
```

Second, you need to remember that `\w` matches both letters, digits and `_` character. So you might better use `[A-Za-z]` character class instead - or just bite the first pair and make RegExp case-insensitive with `i` flag.

As a sidenote, it's really not clear why don't you just use RegExp literal here:

```
/apple:[a-z]+/i.test('apple:asdf')
```

Comment: or instead of `new RegExp(escaped_string)` just use `/apple:[a-z]+/i.test(input)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought is good, but you need to escape your backslashes when using the RegEx constructor. MDN recommends:

> Using the constructor function provides runtime compilation of the
>   regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the
>   regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the
>   pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.

An alternative is the regular expression literal syntax:

> Regular expression literals provide compilation of the regular
>   expression when the script is loaded. If the regular expression
>   remains constant, using this can improve performance.

Try this code:

```
const re = /apple:\w+/
const str = "apple"
re.test(str)
```

[Check out the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to make the Regex a little more general.
And also, since I read match in the question, I thought some other people will look for match expression and not test like I did.

In my case I had to match the word right after a pattern similar to yours (number:). Plus there can be multiple whitespaces after the colons

So, my answer is this, if you need to actually match a word, and not test:

```
'number: 5646 bksfdg df34'.match(/number:\s*([0-9]+)/)
```

In this way, **/s*** says to ignore all the whitespaces until the next pattern and **([0-9]+)** is the matching group of all the subsequent numbers after the "number:" pattern+

If you need to match a word, as @raina77ow suggested, you could use **([a-z]+)** in my regexp

I know this answer more to the title than specifically to the OP, but as I told you I hope this can help others who came here looking for a matching and not testing Regex function