# Issue Generating a Sigma using MathJax (1 success and 1 Fail)

Tags: html, math, mathjax

So I am trying to generate a lower case sigma using a HTML code similar to

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>MathJax example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML" async>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="This_Is_What_I_Want"> $$ \sigma^2 $$</p>
    <p id="Output"></p>
    <p id="Activate"><button onclick="RUN()">Test This out</button></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML,http://myserver.com/MathJax/config/local/local.js">
        function RUN() {
            document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = "$$ \sigma^2 $$";
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The first sigma loads correctly but when I hit the button the second one will not load correctly

## WHY!

Comment: Why? Because JavaScript encodes strings differently from HTML.

Comment: I actually fixed the issue, already in the answer below, I was missing a single \\

Comment: This is not a mathjax issue, this is how work [javascript strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). `console.log("$$ \sigma^2 $$");` output is `$$ sigma^2 $$`. You have to escape backslash or use String.raw(). [Read more on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/how-can-i-use-backslashes-in-a-string#10042082)

Comment: its ok @scraaappy I fixed the issue in the answer provided. I realized I did not read that for the setup provided I have to use \\ if i am attempting to generate this item from my script and using the             MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>MathJax example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML" async>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="This_Is_What_I_Want"> $$ \sigma^2 $$</p>
    <p id="Output"></p>
    <p id="Activate"><button onclick="RUN()">Test This out</button></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML,http://myserver.com/MathJax/config/local/local.js">
        function RUN() {
            document.getElementById("Output").innerHTML = "$$ \\sigma^2 $$";
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

apparently I did not read instructions on the documentation but the default is you need two \ as opposed to one