# MathJax Latex constants are not rendering when EVERYTHING else is

Tags: javascript, html, dom, latex, mathjax

I have a test HTML file that **does** display the value of PI correctly (as a symbol).

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mathDiv">
      $$f(r) = \pi r^2$$
    </div>
    <script src="BinomialExpansion.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a javascript file (BinomialExpansion.js) below that attempts to append the identical equation below using the DOM. This mostly works. All LaTex renders properly **except** for the constant PI. Or any constant that I have tried it on.

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = mathStuff;

function mathStuff() {
  let mathDiv = document.getElementById('mathDiv');
  let testNode = document.createTextNode("$$f(r) = \pi r^2$$");
  mathDiv.appendChild(testNode);
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
}
```

**Screenshot (Chrome)**
[image]

Obviously, I am confused. At first, I thought there might be some sort of race condition being created as the page loads but attaching the code responsible for the DOM manipulation to the `.onload` property of the window object should have fixed the issue if that were the cause. Why is PI not displaying as a symbol when added via the DOM?

Comment: Backslash is an active character in JavaScript. You need to escape it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue Generating a Sigma using MathJax (1 success and 1 Fail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369175/issue-generating-a-sigma-using-mathjax-1-success-and-1-fail)