# how to print "\" with JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that will print a link, but where are this symbol "\" what can't print with JS.

```
document.getElementById('menu_links').innerHTML+="<li><a 
href='CRUD\data.php'>Data</a></li>";
```

Comment: double it \\...

Comment: You should use forward slashes (`/`), not backslashes (`\\`) in URLs anyway.

Comment: Backslash is an escape character. You'll need to escape the escape character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use backslashes (\‌) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/how-can-i-use-backslashes-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

The `'\'` character is an escape character, it needs to be escaped to be printed like:

```
console.log('\\');
```

Will print `'\'`

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the character with another `\`

```js
document.getElementById('menu_links').innerHTML+="<li><a href='CRUD\\data.php'>Data</a><\li>";
console.log('CRUD\\data.php'); //print path
```

```html
<span id="menu_links"></span>
```

**Edit:** always use forward slash for URLs like `http://example.com/CRUD/data.php`, that way you wont have this problem and the code will be compatible across browsers.

Comment: Good answer, but now the URL is using a backslash not a forward slash.

Comment: @evolutionbox is correct, Chrome automatically converts the backslash to a forward slash but that is not true for all browsers so it would be better to just correct it to a forward slash.