# In Node.js, why does my spawn command produce an error?

Tags: node.js

When I run:

```
unzip -p /tmp/document.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g'
```

It correctly extracts the text from my .docx file.

But when I try to wrap this in a Node.js program as follows:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const command = "unzip"; ;
const child = spawn("sh", ["-c", "unzip -p /tmp/document.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g'"]);


const stdout = child.stdout;
const stderr = child.stderr;
const output = "";

stderr.on("data", function(data) {
    console.error("error on stderr", data.toString());
});


stdout.on("data", function(data) {
    output += data;
 });

stdout.on("close", function(code) {

 });
```

I get the following error message:

> error on stderr sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a command line that way in your code, you have to think about the interpretation of the `\` made by node.js and antislash the antislash. One for the node.js one for the sed command.

```
spawn("sh", ["-c", "unzip -p /tmp/document.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\\/w:p>/\\\\n/g; s/<[^>]\\{1,\\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\\n]\\{1,\\}//g'"])
```

---

Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/how-can-i-use-backslashes-in-a-string)

@T.J Crowder

> In JavaScript, the backslash has special meaning both in string
>   literals and in regular expressions. If you want an actual backslash
>   in the string or regex, you have to write two: \.

Comment: An alternative to escaping the string yourself is using the built-in function [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) with a template literal string.

Comment: Yup it's an alternative you can find in the original post made by T.J Crowder. I invite you to go see it and upvote if you find it useful.