# String starting with backslash hacks my regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

My string should be in the IRC command format : "/add john".

So, i created this Regex :

```
var regex = /^\/add ([A-Za-z0-9]+)$/
var bool = regex.test('\/add user1');
alert(bool);
```

The problem is either I use /***/ or RegExp syntax, if I set a backslash at the beginning of my string (like in my example above), my alert pop up show "true" and I don't want that.

I code in Javascript

Comment: Backslash in a string literal is an escape sequence, not an actual backslash. `"\/" === "/"`

Comment: So, how can I do to reject this string '\/add user1' ? Two separate condition tests ?

Comment: `'\/add user1' === '/add user1'`

Comment: I understand now, I didn't know that backslash is automatically deleted in a string type. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/how-can-i-use-backslashes-in-a-string  Thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.raw` to make sure that the backlash is not removed when testing your input:

```js
var regex = /^\/add ([A-Za-z0-9]+)$/
var bool = regex.test(String.raw`\/add user1`);
alert(bool);
```

You can play with this code here: https://jsbin.com/ziqecux/25/edit?js

Comment: Works very well thanks !