# Split String using backslash in javascript

Tags: javascript, split

This is my Temp url and I'm trying to get image name

```
var str='C:\fakepath\alfa_company.png';
```

my expected out put like this:

```
var url='alfa_company.png';
```

Comment: Updated title as this is not jquery - jquery is for DOM manipulation, string manipulation is vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript "\" has a special meaning. 
So, it doesn't get included in your resultant string.

Try

```
let u = String.raw`C:\fakepath\alfa_company.png`;
u.split("\\")[u.split("\\").length-1]
```

or

```
let u = String.raw`C:\fakepath\alfa_company.png`;
u.split("\\").pop()
```

to understand it better go through [How can I use backslashes (\) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/how-can-i-use-backslashes-in-a-string)

Comment: Your answe is perfect working but me filepath store in variable and this situation String.raw function not working so any other function help me

Comment: @MarcinWanago glad to help!
 IMO, there is no way you can manipulate the string to remove the "/" which is an escape character and not a backslash in javascript string. As soon as javascript gets it, "/" behaves like an escape char and not a backslash. You should receive the escaped string in the file value itself i.e. C:\\fakepath\\alfa_company.png

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any jQuery for that :)

```
const path = 'C:\\fakepath\\alfa_company.png';
const filename = path.split('\\').pop(); // alfa_company.png
```

You need to use double backlashes because JavaScript treats them as [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: thank you but only 1 back slash i am get in the file value

Comment: @freedomn-m what was the reason for editing my answer?

Comment: The `\\` in the first string is to generate the string that you already have as a string

Comment: I converted it to a snippet so that OP can see it working.  I also removed the condascending "you don't need any jquery for that :)" - you could put "this is vanilla javascript not jquery" but as it is, sounds very rude and a bit tackky - apologies, I normally include the reason in the edit (like with the snippet edit).  Also, putting the answer first before code can make it easier to find in search / read the answer.

Comment: I find "this is vanilla javascript not jquery" a lot more condescending than my answer :P

Comment: Any answer with ":)" is condescending

Comment: Most people here don't seem to know the / that there is a difference

Comment: Still, could do with converting to a snippet to show it working and putting the answer first rather than last.