# How to make sure that characters from a string are not deleted?

Tags: javascript

I have a string: `let value = "Emrah Tebrikeder120\'\'\'\'\'\'\'";`. When I try to output it to the console, all the \ are deleted. How do I make all the \ in the string appear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041998/how-can-i-use-backslashes-in-a-string answers the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double-backslash, like this:

```js
let value = "Emrah Tebrikeder120\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'";
```

The "\'" is considered as escape sequence.

Comment: I need everything in the string to be replaced in one go. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'everything'?

Comment: "Emrah Tebrikeder120\'\'\'\'\'\'\'" => "Emrah Tebrikeder120\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'"

Comment: Usually, Ctrl+R is the way to go for that.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I mean I need to make a string "normally" using some string method/cycle/function or something. 
**this should not be done manually**.
A "normal" string is a string in which all \ are replaced by \\.

Comment: Ouh, sorry.  I suppose that it should work like this: `let replaced = value.replace("\'", "\\\'")`

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character so, it will be ignored. If you want to keep it, you will need to escape the escape character (put double `\`). Like this:

```js
let value = "Emrah Tebrikeder120\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'\\'";
```