# Replace regex value does not work when there is \d in string

Tags: javascript

I have the below value as a plain text

```
`[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]sdsds\d\d`
```

I want to replace all `[a-ZA-Z]` with `[C]` and replace all `\d` with `[N]`. I tried to do this with the following code, but it does not work for `\d`.

```
value.replace(/\[a-zA-Z\]/g, '[C]').replace(/\\d/g, '[N]').replaceAll('\d', '[N]')
```

The final result must be:

`[C][C][C][C]asass[N][N]`

but it output

`[C][C][C][C]s[N]s[N]s[N][N]`

Note: I am getting this value from API and there is just one `\` before `d` not `\\`.

Comment: Well, for starters. You're using regex as a search pattern when you shouldn't be.

Comment: @John is there any way to do this? I mean replace `\d`

Comment: `.replaceAll('\\d', '[N]')` You have to escape backslash in a string...

Comment: @Nick in this way, the output is `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]sdsdsdd` which is incorrect

Comment: That's not how js strings work. Backslash on its own is an escape character, in order to have one in a string you have to escape it. Two backslashes will result in a single. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10042082/9360315

Comment: If you get `...\d` from a plain text, you can't just put quotation marks around it and expect the result to be an equivalent string in JS (you need to escape the backslash).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here might actually be in your source string.  A literal `\d` in a JavaScript string requires *two* backslashes.  Other than this, your replacement logic is fine.

```js
var input = "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]sdsds\\d\\d";
var output = input.replace(/\[a-zA-Z\]/g, '[C]').replace(/\\d/g, '[N]');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: the problem is, in the input that I am getting from API , there is `\d` in the string not `\\d`

Comment: He doesn't need a regex search query to replace a non dynamic token with a literal string.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with \d. In the case of `'\d'` this will just result in `'d'`. So maybe you wanted `'\\d'` as your starting string?

```js
console.log('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]sdsds\\d\\d'.replaceAll('[a-zA-Z]', '[C]').replaceAll('\\d', '[N]'));
```

Comment: You copied his typo so your snippet doesn't work.

Comment: In the string value, I have `\d` not `\\d`. your code won't work if you change `\\d` to `\d`

Comment: `'\\d'` is you you get a backslash before a d. Go ahead and put `'\d'` in the console, it will just output `d`.