# Keep node from stripping \ (Escape slashes) when saving strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string template that includes the following:

```
    "echo": "echo \"$PWD\""
```

When I save the template to the file system, node strips out the escape characters ( `\` ), so that in the above case the output would be:

```
    "echo": "echo "$PWD""
```

How do we keep node from stripping the escape characters?

Comment: Escape the escape character ```\\```

Comment: Tried how? What form does the template actually take? How is it saved? Please give a [mre].

Comment: Andy escaping the escape character worked!!  Cool thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use backslashes (\\) in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10041998/283366)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This ended up doing the trick (Escape the escape character)!  Thanks Andy!!

```
"echo": "echo \\"$PWD\\""
```