How to keep a single backslash in JavaScript?
I'm working on a project where this string ^\S+@demo\.com$ is stored in a parameter.
It's possible to retrieve it in the JS part using @Params.FiltreEmail.
I can't modify the value of @Params.FiltreEmail beforehand.
I tried to do console.log("@Html.Raw(@Params.FiltreEmail)"); and even
var x = "@Html.Raw(@Params.FiltreEmail)".replace("\\", "\\\\"); 
console.log(x);

but both ways ended up by returning ^S+@demo.com$.
My goal is to be able to define the following regex:
var exp = ("@Html.Raw(@Params.FiltreEmail)" !== "") ? "@Html.Raw(@Params.FiltreEmail)" : "(.*)";
var regex = new RegExp(exp);

How can I achieve this ?

Does this answer your question? How can I use backslashes (\‌) in a string?

You need to JSONEncode on the server.

@AndréLehto https://stackoverflow.com/a/30748739/21518428 this is in a certain way yes, but how can I modify my string then ? I mean I already get it without the \ and since it's a regex expression that can be updated (not on my side) I can not start to parse the string to add \\ after certain characters

To inject a value from Razor into JavaScript, use @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(value)) (without quotes; Json.Encode takes care of both that, and correct escaping).

You need to JSONEncode on the server. @using System.Web.Helpers and @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Params.FiltreEmail))

Just a note: .replace(string will replace the first only - use .replaceAll(string to replace all, or use a regex with /g

The .replace("\\", "\\\\") would only replace the FIRST set, but they would already have been lost when declared.
Instead use server side JSON encode:


// @using System.Web.Helpers

let escapedRegex = `^\\S+@demo\\.com$` // "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Params.FiltreEmail))"; // Server-side rendering happens here

console.log(escapedRegex); // Check if the escaping is done right

let exp = escapedRegex? escapedRegex : "(.*)";
let regex = new RegExp(exp);
console.log(regex); // This should now show /^\S+@demo\.com$/ or /(.*)/




If you're not seeing any slashes when you log the string containing the regular expression directly to the console, it suggests that the slashes are being removed or interpreted in a different way before they reach the console. This might be due to how the framework or environment you're working in processes strings.
In this case try to use
console.log(String.raw(filtreEmail));
